# Error executing a MapReduce from eclipse when hadoop is not in the same host

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I saw several posts dealing with this topic and various webs, and in stackoverflow too, but I don't understand what the real problem is nor what I can do to solve it. The fact is I'm very new with Hadoop.

So, I'm using the Cloudera Quickstart 5.4.2 virtual machine. I developed the typical WordCount sample with the embedded eclipse and everything runs fine.

Now I'm trying to execute the same code in another eclipse outside the virtual machine and am getting a ConnectException.

The connection to the VM is ok, and the creation of my "output" directory is done, but it fails just before execute the map()/reduce() tasks.

To precise my situation :
Host:

- CentOS 6.6 x64 with Oracle JDK 1.7.0_67
- Hadoop 2.6.0 (from Apache) downloaded and unzipped into /opt/hadoop, $HADOOP_HOME has been set and $HADOOP_HOME/bin added to $PATH
- Eclipse Luna and Maven 3.0.4
- The command hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://quickstart:8020/user/cloudera lists all the file I put into this path

VM:

- Cloudera Quickstart 5.4.2 (hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.4.2)
- HDFS is correctly running (checked into Cloudera Manager)

What I saw on internet is some "Hadoop client configuration" in a file mapred-site.xml. This file does not exist in my host, should I create it? Where?

My error is:

```
15/08/28 15:21:09 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/08/28 15:21:10 INFO Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
15/08/28 15:21:10 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
15/08/28 15:21:10 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
15/08/28 15:21:10 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
15/08/28 15:21:10 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/08/28 15:21:10 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
15/08/28 15:21:11 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_local13835919_0001
15/08/28 15:21:11 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
15/08/28 15:21:11 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_local13835919_0001
15/08/28 15:21:11 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter set in config null
15/08/28 15:21:11 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
15/08/28 15:21:11 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter
15/08/28 15:21:11 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
15/08/28 15:21:11 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local13835919_0001_m_000000_0
15/08/28 15:21:11 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
15/08/28 15:21:11 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
15/08/28 15:21:11 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: hdfs://192.168.111.128:8020/user/cloudera/input/download/pg4363.txt:0+408781
15/08/28 15:21:11 INFO mapred.MapTask: (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
15/08/28 15:21:11 INFO mapred.MapTask: mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100
15/08/28 15:21:11 INFO mapred.MapTask: soft limit at 83886080
15/08/28 15:21:11 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
15/08/28 15:21:11 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
15/08/28 15:21:11 INFO mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
15/08/28 15:21:11 WARN hdfs.BlockReaderFactory: I/O error constructing remote block reader.
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.newConnectedPeer(DFSClient.java:3108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.nextTcpPeer(BlockReaderFactory.java:778)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReaderFromTcp(BlockReaderFactory.java:693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.build(BlockReaderFactory.java:354)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:621)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:847)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:897)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.fillBuffer(LineReader.java:180)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.skipUtfByteOrderMark(LineRecordReader.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.nextKeyValue(LineRecordReader.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:556)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/08/28 15:21:11 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:50010 for block, add to deadNodes and continue. java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.newConnectedPeer(DFSClient.java:3108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.nextTcpPeer(BlockReaderFactory.java:778)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReaderFromTcp(BlockReaderFactory.java:693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.build(BlockReaderFactory.java:354)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:621)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:847)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:897)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.fillBuffer(LineReader.java:180)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.skipUtfByteOrderMark(LineRecordReader.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.nextKeyValue(LineRecordReader.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:556)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/08/28 15:21:11 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Could not obtain BP-286282631-127.0.0.1-1433865208026:blk_1073742256_1432 from any node: java.io.IOException: No live nodes contain block BP-286282631-127.0.0.1-1433865208026:blk_1073742256_1432 after checking nodes = [DatanodeInfoWithStorage[127.0.0.1:50010,DS-3299869f-57b5-40b1-9917-9d69cd32f1d2,DISK]], ignoredNodes = null No live nodes contain current block Block locations: DatanodeInfoWithStorage[127.0.0.1:50010,DS-3299869f-57b5-40b1-9917-9d69cd32f1d2,DISK] Dead nodes:  DatanodeInfoWithStorage[127.0.0.1:50010,DS-3299869f-57b5-40b1-9917-9d69cd32f1d2,DISK]. Will get new block locations from namenode and retry...
15/08/28 15:21:11 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DFS chooseDataNode: got # 1 IOException, will wait for 1838.582183063173 msec.
15/08/28 15:21:12 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local13835919_0001 running in uber mode : false
15/08/28 15:21:12 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/08/28 15:21:13 WARN hdfs.BlockReaderFactory: I/O error constructing remote block reader.
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.newConnectedPeer(DFSClient.java:3108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.nextTcpPeer(BlockReaderFactory.java:778)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReaderFromTcp(BlockReaderFactory.java:693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.build(BlockReaderFactory.java:354)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:621)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:847)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:897)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.fillBuffer(LineReader.java:180)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.skipUtfByteOrderMark(LineRecordReader.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.nextKeyValue(LineRecordReader.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:556)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/08/28 15:21:13 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:50010 for block, add to deadNodes and continue. java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.newConnectedPeer(DFSClient.java:3108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.nextTcpPeer(BlockReaderFactory.java:778)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReaderFromTcp(BlockReaderFactory.java:693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.build(BlockReaderFactory.java:354)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:621)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:847)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:897)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.fillBuffer(LineReader.java:180)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.skipUtfByteOrderMark(LineRecordReader.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.nextKeyValue(LineRecordReader.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:556)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/08/28 15:21:13 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Could not obtain BP-286282631-127.0.0.1-1433865208026:blk_1073742256_1432 from any node: java.io.IOException: No live nodes contain block BP-286282631-127.0.0.1-1433865208026:blk_1073742256_1432 after checking nodes = [DatanodeInfoWithStorage[127.0.0.1:50010,DS-3299869f-57b5-40b1-9917-9d69cd32f1d2,DISK]], ignoredNodes = null No live nodes contain current block Block locations: DatanodeInfoWithStorage[127.0.0.1:50010,DS-3299869f-57b5-40b1-9917-9d69cd32f1d2,DISK] Dead nodes:  DatanodeInfoWithStorage[127.0.0.1:50010,DS-3299869f-57b5-40b1-9917-9d69cd32f1d2,DISK]. Will get new block locations from namenode and retry...
15/08/28 15:21:13 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DFS chooseDataNode: got # 2 IOException, will wait for 4651.463132320157 msec.
```

I don't understand why there is any attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:50010, as my hadoop clúster is not on this host, but on the quickstart VM (192.168.x.y, all the /etc/hosts are up to date, too). I suppose I have to configure something, but I don't know what, or where...

I'll try the same thing on Windows 7 x64, configuring winutils and so on, and I've got the same exceptions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems to be a Cloudera Quickstart VM configuration issue. It works with the Hortonworks Sandbox.

The difference is:
- The hortonworks sandbox is configured to use the "real" IP to locate its nodes
- The cloudera VM is configured to use the "localhost" IP to locate its nodes (here, the data node).

So when I tried to execute a MR in my Cloudera virtual cluster from Windows, the configuration returned by the yarn resource manager was 127.0.0.1 instead of the real IP, and of course, I don't have any data node on my local machine.

Comment: I have been trying to get around this issue by modifying the /etc/hosts file in Cloudera VM. However the issue didn't get resolved.